# Unreal Engine: Third person example project and multiplayer

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-4

I was fiddling around with multiplayer stuff in Unreal Engine. I looked into events that run only on server, multicasting events, replication of variables...

But there is something that I dont quite understand: When I load the Third Person example proyect, and enable more than one player, I can see the position and movements of the players being replicated on all clients.

While I understand that the position and the rotation of the players being replicated successfully (since the replication option is enabled in the pawn's blueprint option), I don't really understand why the animations are being replicated. I don't see any reference in the blueprint making animations replicated over the network.

Are pawn animations implicitly replicated on clients when replicating the actor's position? Am I missing some option/configuration I'm missing?

Comment: I don't really understand why you wouldn't want animations to be replicated.  If you're playing a multiplayer game and a player taunts another, why wouldn't you want the player being taunted not to see it?

Comment: I want to replicate the animations, but I want to understand how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character Movement Component is replicating a bunch of stuff for you by default and IIRC has some interpolating features built in, which is why the movement looks smooth even if you have simulated latency.

To my knowledge of the system, the animations aren't really replicated over the network. They are instead only played locally. Since position, rotation and velocity is replicated and interpolated, the animation states should be the same on both computers, creating the illusion that animations are replicated.

Comment: Got this anwser on the UE answer hub. Answered by Weibye.